# When bringing up ROS on a TurtleBot3 Lidar spins once and stops

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same configuration on each of 6 TB3s. But one of them is giving me problems. I believe I have all the software exactly the same, as well as the hardware. Key word is "believe". On this one TB3 when I launch bringup I see the Lidar spin around 1 rotation and then stop. The console output all looks normal. Any ideas?

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
... logging to /home/donatello/.ros/log/60cfcb6c-d8b0-11e9-b88f-b827eb8c90c5/roslaunch-donatello-3080.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://172.22.5.144:44741/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /turtlebot3_core/baud: 115200
 * /turtlebot3_core/port: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /turtlebot3_core/tf_prefix: 
 * /turtlebot3_lds/frame_id: base_scan
 * /turtlebot3_lds/port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    turtlebot3_core (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    turtlebot3_diagnostics (turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics)
    turtlebot3_lds (hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3090]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.22.5.144:11311

setting /run_id to 60cfcb6c-d8b0-11e9-b88f-b827eb8c90c5
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3103]
started core service [/rosout]
process[turtlebot3_core-2]: started with pid [3112]
process[turtlebot3_lds-3]: started with pid [3121]
process[turtlebot3_diagnostics-4]: started with pid [3122]
[INFO] [1568658770.612506]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1568658770.650603]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud
[INFO] [1568658772.787400]: Note: publish buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1568658772.794070]: Setup publisher on sensor_state [turtlebot3_msgs/SensorState]
[INFO] [1568658772.811534]: Setup publisher on firmware_version [turtlebot3_msgs/VersionInfo]
[INFO] [1568658772.881740]: Setup publisher on imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[INFO] [1568658772.891360]: Setup publisher on cmd_vel_rc100 [geometry_msgs/Twist]
[INFO] [1568658772.916308]: Setup publisher on odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]
[INFO] [1568658772.925447]: Setup publisher on joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState]
[INFO] [1568658772.934480]: Setup publisher on battery_state [sensor_msgs/BatteryState]
[INFO] [1568658772.943534]: Setup publisher on magnetic_field [sensor_msgs/MagneticField]
[INFO] [1568658775.020810]: Setup publisher on /tf [tf/tfMessage]
[INFO] [1568658775.034724]: Note: subscribe buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1568658775.036595]: Setup subscriber on cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]
[INFO] [1568658775.049962]: Setup subscriber on sound [turtlebot3_msgs/Sound]
[INFO] [1568658775.064455]: Setup subscriber on motor_power [std_msgs/Bool]
[INFO] [1568658775.077989]: Setup subscriber on reset [std_msgs/Empty]
[INFO] [1568658775.862380]: Setup TF on Odometry [odom]
[INFO] [1568658775.867922]: Setup TF on IMU [imu_link]
[INFO] [1568658775.873850]: Setup TF on MagneticField [mag_link]
[INFO] [1568658775.879245]: Setup TF on JointState [base_link]
[INFO] [1568658775.890412]: --------------------------
[INFO] [1568658775.896054]: Connected to OpenCR board!
[INFO] [1568658775.900610]: This core(v1.2.2) is compatible with TB3 Burger
[INFO] [1568658775.904266]: --------------------------
[INFO] [1568658775.907627]: Start Calibration of Gyro
[INFO] [1568658778.421419]: Calibration End
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333145/when-bringing-up-ros-on-a-turtlebot3-lidar-spins-once-and-stops/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it myself. Let me describe the setup:

A turtlebot3 robot is running roscore on board + the rest of the basic ROS Stack. The robot has a domain name, say r1.brandeis.edu. On the robot,

- ROS_MASTER_URI=http://r1.brandeis.edu:11311
- ROS_HOSTNAME is set to r1.brandeis.edu.

A wifi connected laptop has

- ROS_MASTER_URI=http://r1.brandeis.edu:11311
- ROS_IP=ip-address-of-laptop

This set up works. The problem I had which seemed to be causing the failure was caused by not following that setup.

I remain confused about the interaction between ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME. For example, if on the laptop I setup ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost, this does not work. Also if I have both ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP this causes problems. So I believe I am close to having a robust configuration but there are some interactions which are confusing to me.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2019-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-17**:\

> I solved it myself. Should I delete this question?

No? Why?

It's perfectly OK to answer your own question.

It would be great if you could expand a little on what you mean by "It turned out to be a mismatched ROS_MASTER_URI". More detailed answers will make it easier for future users to re-use those answers.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-09-25**:
@gvdhoorn see above :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also make sure you have the right permissions on /dev/ttyUSB0, e.g.:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2023-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1